# Is there a simple way to add a permanent 'hide' button to items/rows of existing sites?

Tags: javascript, web-development, greasemonkey, userscripts, yahoo-pipes

Is there a simple way to add a 'hide' button to items/rows of existing sites?
The idea is that you don't want to see the same item over and over again.
As a simple example, look at the top reddit posts of all time:

http://www.reddit.com/top/

What I want to accomplish is to interactively hide items permanently, obviously this has to be stored somewhere. I was thinking about HTML5 client side storage, but storing the information on a server is also not a problem.

So is there a simple way to accomplish this? Maybe using tools like Greasemonkey user scripts, bookmarklets, browser extensions, Yahoo pipes, or some other existing solution to this problem?

Comment: Perhaps use AdBlock? Dunno, just a wild thought in my head.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which browser.  But you are in luck. Both Chrome and Firefox have Ad Block.  You'll need to find the right one. The newer Adblock Plus on Chrome (there are two with the same name) has a ui element filter where you just box select the screen and modify the filter from there. Firefox has a similiar one, but it is two separate add ins.

Comment: I use Chromium. By the 'newer' Adblock Plus you mean this one? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb?hl=en-US#  If so, I don't yet understand what you mean by 'box select the screen and modify the filter from there'.